# Proving a limit to be zero

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have problem in proving the following problem using different convergence theorems.

Let $f\in L^p([0,1]), 1\leq p<\infty$, and $E_n\subset[0,1]$ a sequence of measurable sets satisfying $m(E_n)=\frac{1}{n}$, for all $n$. Prove that

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (n^{\frac{p-1}{p}}\int_{E_n}f(x)dx)=0$

I really appreciate any solution and hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p>1$, 
\begin{align*}
n^{(p-1)/p}\displaystyle\int_{E_{n}}|f(x)|dx&\leq n^{(p-1)/p}m(E_{n})^{1/q}\left(\int_{E_{n}}|f(x)|^{p}dx\right)^{1/p}\\
&=n\cdot m(E_{n})^{1/p+1/q}\|f\|_{L^{p}(E_{n})}\\
&=\|f\|_{L^{p}(E_{n})},
\end{align*}
it is a good exercise to prove that if $g\in L^{1}$ then for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that for any measurable set $A$ with $\mu(A)<\delta$, we have $\displaystyle\int_{A}|g|d\mu<\epsilon$.

So with that exercise, one shows that $\|f\|_{L^{p}(E_{n})}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ since $m(E_{n})\rightarrow 0$.

For $p=1$, the result follows by the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f=f^+-f^-$ where $f^+=\max\{f,0\}$ and $f^-=\max\{-f,0\}$. Then $$\inf_{E_n}|f^-|n^{\frac{p-1}{p}}m(E_n)\leq n^{\frac{p-1}{p}}\int_{E_n}f(x)dx\leq \sup_{E_n}|f^+|n^{\frac{p-1}{p}}m(E_n)$$